# Retrieve contents of _source only- Elasticsearch ( Node JS)

Tags: elasticsearch

According to [Retrieving a document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/get-doc.html) documentation

```
 GET /website/blog/123/_source
```

would directly return the document stored inside the `_source` field.
I'm currently using Node JS's express framework. How should I implement this in my code?

```
esClient.search({
        index: "myIndex",
        type: "myType",
        body: {

            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "size": 3,
            "from": 1

        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        var result = resp.hits.hits;
        res.status(200).send({data: {recommendations: result, showItemFrom: showItemFrom}})
    }, function (err) {
        console.trace(err.message)
        res.status(500).send({data: err.message})
    })
```

I'm getting the response this way...

```
[
  "_source":{
             {
                 "id": 1,
                 "title": "Test"
                }
            } 
]
```

However, I want it this way...

```
[
   {
      id:1,
      title:"Test"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the Elasticsearch API has a method to do that for searches, the one that Val mentioned works, but it is only usable to GET documents directly through its id.

But you can map the result using the Javascript [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
var result = resp.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source);
```

Comment: Perfect single line solution.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
index:"myIndex"
```

Add:

```
source:true
```

Comment: That didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [`getSource()` function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-getsource), like this:

```
esClient.getSource({
    index: "website",
    type: "blog",
    id: "123"
}).then(function (source) {
   // do something with source
}, function (err) {
   // error happened
})
```